# HTTP Status 500 .. fulfilling this request. exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, tomcat7

Hi I can't figure out where the mistake comes from after executing my program:
Here is my code in my java application:

```
public class StudentServlet extends GenericServlet {

@Override
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // getDataFromBrowserWindows WITH ServletRequest Interface : 

        getParemeter(String args)
        int sno=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("sno"));
        String sname=req.getParameter("sname");
        String sadd=req.getParameter("sadd");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();


        try {
            ps.setInt(1,sno);
            ps.setString(2,sname);
            ps.setString(3,sadd);

        int count=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(count!=0)
                    // to write directly on the webpage
                   //NOT System.out.println("data is inserted");
                   // but like this
                    pw.println("data is inserted")'
        else 
            pw.println("data is not inserted");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    pw.println(sno+"\t"+sname+"\t"+sadd);
    System.out.println("Service");

}

/**
 * Constructor of the object.
 */
public StudentServlet() {
    super();
    System.out.println("Constructor");
}

/**
 * Destruction of the servlet. <br>
 */
public void destroy() {
    super.destroy(); // Just puts "destroy" string in log
    // Put your code here
    System.out.println("Destroy");
}

/**
 * Initialization of the servlet. <br>
 *
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurs
 */
ServletConfig sg=null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;
Connection con=null;

public void init(ServletConfig sg) throws ServletException {
    // Put your code here

    try {
        con=JdbcUtility.getConnection();
        //ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    //in sql --> QueryConstants.insert_qry in QueryConstants.java

        ps=con.prepareStatement(QueryConstants.insert_qry);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Init");
}
```

}

my code in html:

```
<form action="./servlet/StudentServlet">
Sno<input type="text" name="sno" /><br>
Sname<input type="text" name="sname" /><br>
Sadd<input type="text" name="sadd" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Insert" />
```

my code in my java file for query:

```
public interface QueryConstants {
    String insert_qry="insert into student values(?,?,?)";


}
```

after executing, my error message in my html page is following:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from 

fulfilling this request.

exception

**java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.shiva.handler.StudentServlet.service(StudentServlet.java:32)**

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
```

logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56

Please help...Thanks!

Comment: Have another go at formatting the code in this question. You'll have a hard time getting people to help you with the answer when it is so difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi I can't figure out where the mistake comes from after executing my program

The exception message tells you *exactly* what (and where) the problem is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.shiva.handler.StudentServlet.service(StudentServlet.java:32)
```

You are trying to call methods on an object that is null - and this happens on line 32 of your `StudentServlet` class.

I'm not sure what that line of code is.  But either your logic is incorrect (something might actually be null, and you need to account for this), or it's a sign that your environment/initialisation is incorrect (e.g. something didn't get set up).

Have a look at that line, and ensure the null case is handled.  And in future - **read the error messages**, as you stand almost no chance of understanding a problem without doing that.